# Force HAProxy to lookup DNS for backend server

Tags: domain-name-system, haproxy

I have haproxy 1.5.8, it proxies some requests (based on the path) to a third-party we have no control over.

Since the IP of backend server is resolved once at startup, it breaks if the IP change.

If there a workaround for that ? In nginx it's possible to declare an internal variable and have it cached for X seconds. I didn't found a similar solution for HAProxy.

Answer (score 28):

With the recent release of HAProxy 1.6 there is a solution to your problem. You can now define resolvers and associate these to your backend. IP resolution will then be done at runtime.

```
resolvers dns
  nameserver public-0  xx.xx.xx.xx:53
  hold valid 1s

frontend http
  bind *:8000
  default_backend site-backend

backend site-backend
  balance leastconn
  server site sub.example.com:80 resolvers dns check inter 1000
```

[StackOverflow discussing this](https://serverfault.com/questions/704482/haproxy-resolvers-section-amazon-elb)

[Link to the corresponding documentation](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#5.3.2)

Comment: hmmm when I do this and begin refreshing the page, I end up getting a 503 within a minute or so

Comment: i had to have multiple duplicate "server" lines https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/trouble-with-dns-resolvers-sticking-to-single-ip-address/146/30

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it seems like this is still a [work in progress.](https://www.mail-archive.com/haproxy@formilux.org/msg11736.html)

Have you considered using a separate nginx proxy? So that you forward requests for that backend to an nginx instance, which then does DNS resolution and forwards the request? Not ideak, but may work in a lower traffic environment.

Comment: There's always that solution, but hoping to find a solution that would keep it simple.