# Haproxy Resolvers Section + Amazon ELB

Tags: domain-name-system, haproxy

I'm currently using Haproxy-1.6-dev2 in front of an amazon ELB, and I'm running into DNS resolution issues.  I'm working with the dev version of haproxy because of the new `resolvers` feature, but haven't been able to have Haproxy trigger a change in it's internal ip address listing for a server without restarting the haproxy process.  Amazon updates the IPs of its ELBs and Haproxy continues using the old IP addresses without updating. A simplified config file is below.

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1   local0
    stats socket /var/run/haproxy.sock

defaults
    log global
    mode http
    option httpchk GET /
    option log-health-checks
    option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000

resolvers dns
    nameserver public-0  xx.xx.xx.xx:53
    hold valid 1s

frontend http
    bind *:8000
    default_backend site-backend

backend site-backend
    balance leastconn
    server site sub.example.com:80 resolvers dns check inter 1000
```

I create a temporary A record in AWS Route53, and the health check fails because the A record points to an invalid location.
I then update the A record to point to a valid location and the health  check continues to fail. A simple restart of haproxy means the health checks start passing.

I also pinged the stats socket to get a bit more info:

```
 nameserver public-0:
  sent: 153
  valid: 0
  update: 0
  cname: 0
  cname_error: 0
  any_err: 0
  nx: 0
  timeout: 0
  refused: 0
  other: 0
  invalid: 0
  too_big: 0
  outdated: 51
```

The haproxy documentation did not offer much help as to what "outdated" might mean.

Answer (score 2):

Please run HAProxy in debug mode ('debug' statement in global section or '-d' when running haproxy deamon) and report here output of stdout and stderr.

In the mean time, please take a tcpdump of the DNS traffic of the box and send it to the dev who did the DNS work in HAProxy: bedis9@gmail.com.

Baptiste

Comment: Like I mentioned in my email to you, seems to be a matter of an 1ms default timeout instead of a 1ms default timeout.  Setting `timeout retry 1s` should resolve the issue for anyone else with this problem on Haproxy-1.6-dev2.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this!
Bug now fixed and patched sent to upstream. Waiting for Willy to integrate it.

Baptiste

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a matter of an 1ms default timeout instead of a 1s default timeout. Setting `timeout retry 1s` should resolve the issue for anyone else with this problem on Haproxy-1.6-dev2.  I imagine this will be resolved in the official 1.6 release.